Numba function performance slows down when calling it multiple times in for loop
In my python code, I work with a numba function which is called inside a for loop in every iteration. The number of iterations depends on the length of the list and can be up to 20.000 iterations.
I observe that the performance time of the called numba function slows down over the course of iterations. For the first approx. 1000 iterations, the numba function has a performance time of approx. 0.4 - 0.6 seconds. After that, the performance time of the numba function per iteration slows down until 1.6 seconds in the last iterations.
This is general structure of the code:
EDIT: I replaced the previously mentioned code structure here with an MVP. In this code, the problem arises even faster, after 100 - 200 iterations.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit, prange
import copy
import random
import time


# Create simulated combinations list with 1000 different combination dictionaries
simulated_combinations_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    simulated_combinations_list.append({"a": random.randint(50, 550), "b": random.randint(50, 550), "c": random.randint(50, 550), "d": random.randint(50, 550)})

    
# Create simulated arrays list
simulated_array_list = []
rows = 1380
columns = 17

for i in range(3000):
    # Simulate 2d array
    simulated_array_list.append(np.random.rand(rows, columns))


    
# Create MVP of numba function
@njit(parallel=True)
def numba_function(array_list, a_value, b_value, c_value, d_value):
        
    # Get number of arrays in list
    number_of_arrays = len(array_list)

    # Loop through array_list and perform actions for each 2D array simultaneously --> usage of prange
    for i in prange(number_of_arrays):
        current_array = array_list[i]

        data_manipulated = False

        # Loop through every row of current 2D array
        for j in range(current_array.shape[0]):
            row = current_array[j]

            value_column_3 = row[2]

            # Make some if else checks for different values in that row and manipulate values in that row if a statement 
            # is true. I simplified the checks here a little bit, because the problem can still be reproduced
            if data_manipulated == False:
                if row[4] <= value_column_3 + a_value:
                    row[11] = 1
                    row[15] = (value_column_3 * 2) + a_value
                    row[16] = row[0]
                    data_manipulated = True

                elif row[4] >= value_column_3 + b_value:
                    row[12] = 1
                    row[15] = ((value_column_3 * 2) * (-1)) + b_value
                    row[16] = row[0]
                    data_manipulated = True

                elif row[4] >= value_column_3 + c_value:
                    row[13] = 1
                    row[15] = (value_column_3 * 3) + c_value
                    row[16] = row[0]
                    data_manipulated = True

                elif row[4] >= value_column_3 + d_value:
                    row[14] = 1
                    row[15] = (value_column_3 * 3) + d_value
                    row[16] = row[0]
                    data_manipulated = True


            # if current row is end of array and nothing was manipulated
            if (current_array.shape[0] - 1) and (data_manipulated == False):
                row[15] = 0
                row[16] = row[0]


        # after loop through every row has ended for current array
        # find manipulated row
        cond1 = current_array[:, 11] == 1
        cond2 = current_array[:, 12] == 1
        cond3 = current_array[:, 13] == 1
        cond4 = current_array[:, 14] == 1
        cond5 = current_array[:, 16] != 0
        indeces = np.where(cond1 | cond2 | cond3 | cond4)
        row_index = indeces[0]

        # if manipulated rows were found
        if len(row_index) > 0:

            #Replace first row of current array with manipulated row
            current_array[0, :] = current_array[row_index, :]

        # Replace current array in array list with manipulated array
        array_list[i] = current_array

    #Return manipulated array list
    return array_list



# Loop through combinations list and call numba functions on array list with different variables a, b, c, d
counter = 0
for combination in simulated_combinations_list:
    a_value = combination.get("a")
    b_value = combination.get("b")
    c_value = combination.get("c")
    d_value = combination.get("d")
    
    # deep copy simulated array list twice for calling in numba functions:
    array_list_copy_one = [copy.deepcopy(element) for element in simulated_array_list]
    array_list_copy_two = [copy.deepcopy(element) for element in simulated_array_list]
    
    # I call two separate numba functions which have the same structure but different if else manipulating questions, 
    # to simulate that I call the same numba function twice here. It reproduces the same problem with the increasing 
    # performance time over the iterations
    start_time_numba = time.time()
    result_list_one = numba_function(array_list_copy_one, a_value, b_value, c_value, d_value)
    result_list_two = numba_function(array_list_copy_two, a_value, b_value, c_value, d_value)
    end_time_numba = time.time()
    diff_time = end_time_numba - start_time_numba
    print(f"Execution time numba functions round {counter}: {diff_time} seconds.")
    
    counter += 1
    
    # After the numba functions I process them further and save results in a SQLite3 database. I did not mention this
    # code here as the increased performance time of the numba functions over the course of iterations occurs also without that part

Is there maybe any overhead or garbage which grows bigger over time therefore causes the performance decrease?
My expectation was that the performance time of the numba function should be nearly the same over the complete for loop, since it gets always an argument with the same sizes, just different values and creates always a result list which is then further processed after the numba function.

There isn't enough information in your code. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

In general, Numba does not behave that way, and your expectation is correct. So the cause must be something else. That is why we need an MRE.

Thanks for your comments, I edited the question and included the MVP code. Hopefully, this makes the problem more clear for you

that's a lot of code. Can you trim it down?

I cannot reproduce this problem. Execution time is consistent on my machine. Maybe the explanation is outside of your program: perhaps the OS deprioritizes your script (windows for example tries to give priority to the "active" window)

@julaine thanks for your comment. I already trimmed it down very much, but I can try to make it smaller. Strange that on your machine the execution time is consistent. On my machine it nearly doubles and when using more than the 1000 combinations from this example it gets even worse. I use a windows as OS and the problem still arises when nothing else is opened but this script.

Try this: add cached=True to the njit-method (to make the first iteration fast) then call your script twice, one after the other (like python3 script.py ; python3 script.py) Does the second execution start fast or slow? If it starts slow, the effect must have a cause outside your program.

modern CPUs measure their temperature and reduce clock-speed if they get too hot. That could cause the effect you describe.

I was able to reproduce the problem. And I think I found half of the problem here. If I replace the numba_function call with result_list_one = array_list_copy_one (and *_two as well), it still behaves the same way. So this has nothing to do with numba, probably caused by Python's memory management. But it is not clear to me why the time is increasing.
